# How to execute http requests in a Spring application without using WebFlux/RestTemplate (webmvc)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Spring application, I need to perform GET and rarely POST requests. The application is standalone (not a WEB application). It will not process any incoming requests. It lacks controllers/routers, etc. I'm trying to find a "convenient" solution for making requests. I made a choice in the direction of `WebFlux`, but realized that in this case, this is the same thing that I connected to my webmvc application and it became a WEB application. I would like to avoid connecting so much of a large component, most of which will not be used. How would it be in this situation? Abandon `WebFlux` in the direction of `java.net.http.HttpClient` (Java 11) or another analog, or a bare HttpConnection?

Java 18, SpringBoot 2.7.5-SNAPSHOT

```
dependencies {
    // implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux' ?
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test' ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.net.http.HttpClient` of Java 11 as you already mentioned. Using `HttpConnection` is an option but I wouldn't recommend it. In addition you can just use any 3d party Http client. Here are 2 most popular ones:

1. [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/)
2. [OK Http client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/)

Besides those - and this is shameless self-promotion - I wrote my own Http client. I don't mean to compete with fullness of features with any of the above clients, but my client is very simple in use and does support basic functionality which in most cases is enough. It is part of MgntUtils Open source library written and maintained by me. Here is a Javadoc for [HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html) class. The library you can get as maven artifacts on Maven central [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) with source code and Javadoc.